# How to redirect the subdomain of a domain - Blogger

Tags: domain, redirect, subdomain, cname-record, a-record

I have a blogger blog put up, and Google told me to add some A records in order to enable a www-free redirection to the full www domain. So by adding those, visiting bitfalls.com (which is my blog) should go to www.bitfalls.com, but this does not happen. Instead, I get a not found error. Is there anything else I should do? The records are as follows:

[image]

Interestingly, even blog.bitfalls.com fails with a not found error, only when prefixed with www does it work.

The other part of the question is - since my domain name is registered at name.com, and I simply redirect the bitfalls.com domain to bitfalls.blogspot.com as per Google's guides, how can I redirect a subdomain of the site, for example, code.bitfalls.com, to go to a specific folder on my hosting provider (hostgator - not name.com), without it triggering the blog?

Comment: How is this off topic? Where am I supposed ask questions like these if not here? The closing without explanation is what's off topic.

Answer (score 3):

You want to CNAME `www` to `bitfalls.com` not `ghs.google.com`. The same is true for your `blog` record.

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried this and will keep checking until it propagates. Any hints on the other issue? code.bitfalls.com redirecting to a completely server/host?